# Wrap a sub-string containing a dollar sign with a <strong> using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this HTMl from a db, 
`<p>$10 remaining of $100 budget</p>`

I'd like to wrap the $10 with a `<strong>` tag as below.

The dollar amount could change to be more than 2 digits, and I'd like to wrap the entire amount.

The result I'm seeking using jQuery/JS is...

```
<p><strong>$10<strong> remaining of $100 budget</p>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is it always going to be the string "$10"? Or just the first number after a $? Or the first word everytime?

Comment: first number after the $. I edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do :

```
$('p').html(function(_, old){
     return old.replace(/(\$\d+) /, '<strong>$1</strong> ');
})
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gEfzs/

Comment: i don't think its always $10.

Comment: @HarshitTailor yeah he just edited his question, working on a regexp

Comment: Thanks, yeah sorry, i just edited the question for clarity :)

Comment: working, thx. and if the dollar has commas, I used this regex:

    ^\$?[0-9]+(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]{2})?$

Answer (score 2):

You can do this all with string manipulation. [DEMO](http://codepen.io/Fresheyeball/pen/CJacF)
Someone else could probably do this more efficiently with Regex but hey this works fine.

```
var priceStr = "<p>$10 remaining of $100 budget</p>";
// remove <p>
priceStr     = priceStr.substr("<p>".length, priceStr.length);
// convert to array and get `$10` as first element
var priceStrArr  = priceStr.split(' ');
// replace first element in array `$10` with wrapping string
priceStr = priceStr.replace(priceStrArr[0], '<p><strong>'+priceStrArr[0]+'</strong>');
// output
$('#thingy').html(priceStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex something like this `\$[0-9]{2}\b` with javascript [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<p>$10 remaining of $100 budget</p>
```

JS

```
var html = $('p').html();
var index = html.indexOf('$');
var parts, part1, part2;
if (index != -1) {
    part1 = html.substring(0, index);
    part2 = html.substring(index);
    parts = part2.split(' ');
    parts[0] = '<strong>' + parts[0] + '</strong>';
    html = part1 + parts.join(' ');
    $('p').html(html);
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46JK7/)**